# Unable to Connect Jackal to the Internet to get updates

Tags: jackal

I am having an issue connecting jackal to the internet. When trying to install or update any apt packages, I get errors like these when running sudo apt-get update:

```
temporary failure resolving 'packages.ros.org','archive.ubuntu.com', ‘packages.clearpathrobotics.com’, etc.
```

Reading online, it seems that this is an issue with the jackal not being able to obtain the IP address for the website, (ex: packages.ros.org). I’ve tried pinging DNS address to 8.8.8.8, which seems to be working.  The network I am using shouldn’t have any firewall settings interfering.

We are connected to a network with internet capabilities and I verified that the web browser works. I am at a loss for what could be causing this issue, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you currently communicating with the jackal? Are you connected directly to the jackal motherboard, or are you using ssh over a wifi network? Have you verified that the time-of-day is correct on the jackal?